# Slider not working using nextjs and tailwinds css

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, carousel

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const textData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Text 1 Description",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Text 2 Description",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Text 3 Description",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "Text 4 Description",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "Text 5 Description",
  },
];

export default function TextSlider() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const handlePrev = () => {
    setCurrentIndex(
      (prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + textData.length) % textData.length
    );
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % textData.length);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full h-screen overflow-hidden">
      <button
        className="absolute top-1/2 left-4 text-white text-2xl z-50"
        onClick={handlePrev}
      >
        {"<"}
      </button>
      <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
        <div
          className="flex transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out"
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(-${
              (currentIndex * 100) / textData.length - 40
            }%)`,
          }}
        >
          {textData.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={item.id}
              className={`w-[100vh] h-full flex items-center justify-center ${
                index === currentIndex ? "transform scale-125" : "opacity-75"
              }`}
            >
              <div className="bg-black bg-opacity-50 text-white p-4">
                <p className="text-lg font-bold text-center">{item.text}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className="absolute top-1/2 right-4 text-white text-2xl"
        onClick={handleNext}
      >
        {">"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. I tried to create a slider but there is an error

   TranslateX doesnt work that good like I can't see the 1 and 2 elements when i have -{formula} and i cant see 4 and 5 when i have {formula} without "-", also is starting from element 3 being in center so this is the main issue. If i swipe next,it will remain on 3 when elements 1 and 2 are active,but when element 4 is active it will scroll to it.

   so the errors are:

   1. element 3 being in the center automatically because translatex is 0% and it will take automatically the center of the div with the generated elements
   2. the swiping system is not really working because 3 is in the center so it will continue after 5 to swipe to empty until it reach elemnt 3 and it will go to it,so elements 1 and 2 are unreachable

I tried to fix the issue by adding -40 at the translatex value. It is kinda working because the swiping stops at 5 and start again from 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. There was a justify-center that was centering the carousel div, so to fix this issue I just removed the justify-center who is centering the div.
Edit: also removed the -40 .